# How to get photo in real size (not thumb) from telegram?

Tags: java, api, telegram-bot

I am using getFile() and then download photo with a link like `https://api.telegram.org/file/bot<token>/<file_path>.`
But I received only his thumbnails

Can anyone ask me how to download photo in real size?

Comment: I upload photp By Android mobile app "Telegram". Just send photo to my bot

Comment: Make sure to read through the documentation of the API you are using first before attempting to ask questions about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `photo` object you receive from Telegram contains an array with the `file_id` of different sizes. The higher the index, the bigger the size, so you just need to pick the right `file_id`
.

It could look like this:

```
[{
    "file_id":"AgADBAADxxxx",
    "file_size":19374,
    "width":253,
    "height":320
},{
    "file_id":"AgADBAACxxxx",
    "file_size":75657,
    "width":632,
    "height":800
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use PHP: you can write this line for full size:

> $file_id = $updates['message']['photo'][1]['file_id'];

and this line for thumb:

> $file_id = $updates['message']['photo'][0]['file_id'];

Comment: Actually, there can be more than two sizes. So to get the full size, get the last element of the array, not the second one.